# Why do 'for' and 'for_each' result in different functions being generated by iterating through array elements using lambdas?

Tags: c++, lambda, callback

I'm trying to better understand the interactions of lambda expressions and iterators.

What is the difference between these three snippets of code? onSelect is an std::function that is called when a component is selected.

Example 1 and 3 seem to work quite nicely. Example 2 returns the same index value, regardless of the component clicked.

My intuition is that Example 2 only results in one symbol being generated, and therefore the function only points to the first value. My question is, why would for_each result in multiple function definitions being generated, and not the normal for loop?

```
components[0].onSelect = [&]{ cout<<0; };
components[1].onSelect = [&]{ cout<<1; };
components[2].onSelect = [&]{ cout<<2; };
components[3].onSelect = [&]{ cout<<3; };
//And so on
```

vs

```
for (int i = 0; i < numComponents; ++i)
{
    components[i].onSelect = [&]
    {
        cout<<components[i];
    };
}
```

vs

```
int i = 0;
std::for_each (std::begin (components), std::end (components), [&](auto& component)
{
    component.onSelect = [&]{
        cout<<i;
});
```

Comment: Why do you think the `for_each` version will do anything at all to `i`?

Comment: The second and the third codes lead to undefined behavior due to references to destroyed variables.

Comment: By "returns the same index value", do you mean it _prints the same `components[i]` several times_? Why is #2 printing `components[i]` instead of `i` in the first place?

Comment: Accepted @useless's answer. Passing 'i' by value instead of reference shows that the results have nothing to do with the nature of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the difference between these three snippets of code?

Well, only the first one is legal.

> My intuition is that Example 2 only results in one symbol being generated

Each lambda expression generates a unique unnamed class type in the smallest enclosing scope. You have one block scope (inside the `for` loop) and one lambda expression so yes, there's only one type.

Each *instance* of that type (one per iteration) could differ in *state*, because they *could* all capture different values of `i`. They don't, though, they all capture exactly the same lexical scope *by reference*.

> and therefore the function only points to the first value

A lambda expression is always a class type, not a function. A lambda expression with an empty capture is *convertible* to a free function pointer - but you don't have an empty capture. Finally, the lambda didn't *capture* only the first value - or any value - but an unusable reference to the variable `i`. Because you explicitly asked to capture by reference (`[&]`) instead of value.

That is, they all get the same reference to `i` whatever its particular value at the time they're instantiated, **and** `i` will have been set to `numComponents` and then gone out of scope before any of them can be invoked. So, even if it hadn't gone out of scope, referring to `components[i]` would almost certainly be Undefined Behaviour. But as it has gone out of scope, it is a dangling reference. This is an impressive density of bugs in a small amount of code.

Compare the minimal change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numComponents; ++i) {
    components[i].onSelect = [i, &components]
    {
        cout<<components[i];
    };
}
```

which captures `i` by *value*, which is presumably what you really wanted, and only takes `components` by reference. This works correctly with no UB.

> My question is, why would for_each result in multiple function definitions being generated, and not the normal for loop?

You have two nested lambda expressions in example 3, but we're only concerned with the inner one. That's still a single lambda expression in a single scope, so it's only generating one class type. The main difference is that the `i` to which it has (again) captured a reference, has presumably not gone out of scope by the time you try calling the lambda.

For example, if you actually wrote (and a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would have shown this explicitly)

```
int i = 0;
std::for_each (std::begin (components), std::end (components), [&](auto& component)
{
    component.onSelect = [&]{
        cout<<i;
});
for (i = 0; i < numComponents; ++i)
  components[i].onSelect();
```

then the reason it would *appear* to work is that `i` happens to hold the expected value whenever you call the lambda. Each copy of it still has a reference to the same local variable `i` though. You can demonstrate this by simply writing something like:

```
int i = 0;
std::for_each (std::begin (components), std::end (components), [&](auto& component)
{
    component.onSelect = [&]{
        cout<<i;
});
components[0].onSelect();
components[1].onSelect();
i = 2;
components[1].onSelect();
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense. So `for (int i = 0; i < numComponents; ++i) {
    components[i].onSelect = [i, &components]
    {
        cout<<components[i];
    };
}`

and

`for (int i = 0; i < numComponents; ++i) {
    components[i].onSelect = [&]
    {
        cout<<components[i];
    };
}`

would effectively generate different results because 'i' is being passed in by value, and not by reference. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: FWIW, you can also write a lambda printing out the address `&i`, and see how that varies when you capture `i` by value and reference in different situations. You should certainly be using value here, but it's a quick & easy check.